# Error building libpthreads-stubs-0.3 on Windows

Tags: mingw, pthreads-win32, vaapi

I am trying to compile libpthreads-stubs-0.3 (for vaapi) on a Windows machine which has MinGW and MSys environment. I have installed mingw32-pthreads-w32 dev package(version 2.9.1-1) in MinGW.

Now when i try to compile libpthreads-stubs-0.3 (there is only one file called `stubs.c`) i get a conflicting types error:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Pawan/Downloads/Compressed/libpthread-stubs-0.3/libpthread-stubs-0.3'
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2  -MT stubs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/stubs.Tpo -c -o stubs.lo stubs.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2  -MT stubs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/stubs.Tpo -c stubs.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/stubs.o

stubs.c:36:5: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_self'
 int pthread_self() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
     ^
In file included from stubs.c:29:0:
c:\mingw\include\pthread.h:955:37: note: previous declaration of 'pthread_self' was here
 PTW32_DLLPORT pthread_t PTW32_CDECL pthread_self (void);
                                     ^

stubs.c:153:5: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_exit'
 int pthread_exit() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_exit_stub")));
     ^
In file included from stubs.c:29:0:
c:\mingw\include\pthread.h:950:32: note: previous declaration of 'pthread_exit' was here
 PTW32_DLLPORT void PTW32_CDECL pthread_exit (void *value_ptr);
                                ^
stubs.c:162:5: warning: 'pthread_equal' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 int pthread_equal() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_equal_stub")));
     ^
stubs.c: In function '__pthread_equal_stub':
stubs.c:187:16: error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'pthread_t' and 'pthread_t')
     return (t1 == t2);
                ^
make[1]: *** [stubs.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Pawan/Downloads/Compressed/libpthread-stubs-0.3/libpthread-stubs-0.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now when i comment the `#include <pthread.h>` on the top of file and put it inside `ifndef` (because if i don't i get a error: `error: unknown type name 'pthread_t'` which is obvious) i get the same error as above:

```
#ifdef NEED_EQUAL_STUB
#include <pthread.h>
static int __pthread_equal_stub(pthread_t t1, pthread_t t2)
{
    return (t1 == t2);
}
#endif
```

**Edit:** Stubs.c file code

```
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC

//#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "config.h"

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_SELF
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_self() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_self = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_mutex_init() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_mutex_init = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_DESTROY
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_mutex_destroy() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_mutex_destroy = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_LOCK
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_mutex_lock() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_mutex_lock = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_UNLOCK
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_mutex_unlock() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_mutex_unlock = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_INIT
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_cond_init() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_cond_init = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_DESTROY
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_cond_destroy() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_cond_destroy = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_CONDATTR_INIT
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_condattr_init() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_condattr_init = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_CONDATTR_DESTROY
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_condattr_destroy() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_condattr_destroy = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_WAIT
#define NEED_ABORT_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_cond_wait() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_abort_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_cond_wait = __pthread_abort_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT
#define NEED_ABORT_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_cond_timedwait() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_abort_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_cond_timedwait = __pthread_abort_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_SIGNAL
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_cond_signal() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_cond_signal = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_BROADCAST
#define NEED_ZERO_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_cond_broadcast() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_zero_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_cond_broadcast = __pthread_zero_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_EXIT
#define NEED_EXIT_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_exit() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_exit_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_exit = __pthread_exit_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_PTHREAD_EQUAL
#define NEED_EQUAL_STUB
# ifdef SUPPORT_ATTRIBUTE_ALIAS
int pthread_equal() __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("__pthread_equal_stub")));
# else
#  pragma weak pthread_equal = __pthread_equal_stub
# endif
#endif

#ifdef NEED_ZERO_STUB
static int __pthread_zero_stub()
{
    return 0;
}
#endif

#ifdef NEED_ABORT_STUB
static int __pthread_abort_stub()
{
    abort();
}
#endif

#ifdef NEED_EQUAL_STUB
//#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include <pthread.h>
static int __pthread_equal_stub(pthread_t t1, pthread_t t2)
{
    return (t1 == t2);
}
#endif

#ifdef NEED_EXIT_STUB
static void __pthread_exit_stub(void *ret)
{
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Can you post your file stubs.c? The only time I've had this happen was when different files were including different headers in different locations but with the same name, but since you only have one file I don't think that would be it.

Comment: @mgarey i have added the stubs.c file. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your error but did (I think) successfully install  libpthreads-stubs-0.3. I'm using the 64-bit version of msys and mingw.

I downloaded libpthreads-stubs-0.3 from [this website](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/), used tar -xzf to extract the it to my home folder in msys, cd'd into the folder, and did `./configure --prefix=/usr` then `make` then `make install`.

I once had the `error: conflicting types for ...` and `error: previous declaration for ...` and it was because I was including mingw's pthreads.h in one place and a different version of pthreads.h for Windows elsewhere.

If all else fails, try starting over your installation of mingw and libpthreads-stubs-0.3 from scratch.